# In C++, is there a practical way to restrict the calling of one function to certain function?

Tags: c++

C++ does not support nested function. Say I have function a and b, I want to guarantee that only a can call b, and nobody else can, is there a way of doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but you can always create a function-level class. For example:

```
void MyFunction() {

    class InnerClass {
    public:
        static void InnerFunction() {
        }
    };

    InnerClass::InnerFunction();
    InnerClass::InnerFunction();
    // ...

};
```

Comment: I don't why other people don't like your solution (can anyone comment?), it seems to me is the easiest and most practical way of doing the job.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but FWIW, (1) this [won't work](https://godbolt.org/z/s64chTYb6) if `InnerFunction` is a template; (2) anytime this _would_ work, you can/should just [use a lambda](https://godbolt.org/z/Eob4YsWbY) instead; (3) typically you break code up into functions so that you can move it _out_ of line. Answerers/voters here naturally assume that you want to limit the callers of an ordinary _out-of-line_ function, not (as here) simply take that function and in-line it into the scope where it's used. (This also means this approach fails if there are _two_ callers.)

Comment: I wrote this answer before lambdas were widely supported in C++. The asker himself wrote: _"C++ does not support nested function."_ which suggests they were *not* looking for "out-of-line" function. And finally, `MyFunction` itself can be made a template and then the template parameter used inside `InnerFunction`, which may or may not be enough in a specific situation.

Answer (score 6):

There are multiple ways of doing this (none are 100% bulletproof, someone can always edit your source files), but one way would

1. Put the function inside a class, make it private, and make the functions that you want to have the ability to call it "friends."
2. Assuming you want function `a` to be callable by function `b` but no one else, another way would be to put `a` and `b` in their own source file together and make `a` `static`. This way, `a` would only be visible to entities in the same source file, but `b` would be visible to everyone who had it's signature.

Or 3. If you can use lambdas (i.e. your compiler supports this feature of C++11):

```
void a() {
    auto f = []() { /* do stuff */ }

    f();
}
```

Comment: Note that lambdas are C++11 only. (Perhaps that's why someone downvoted?)

Comment: @AndrewMarshall I don't know why though, I said "If you can use lambdas"

Comment: I don't know who downvoted it (I upvoted it), but I like Branko's method most. It seems that your methods are kind of exotic.

Comment: @JohnYang I guess I'm just an exotic kind of a guy.

Answer (score 4):

```
int main()
{
    class a
    {
        public:
            static void foo(){}
    };
    a::foo();
}
```

It compiles fine for me, so you can have "nested functions" in C++

Answer (score 3):

The [passkey idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220009/is-this-key-oriented-access-protection-pattern-a-known-idiom).

```
class KeyForB{
  // private ctor
  KeyForB(){}
  friend void a();
};

void a(){
  b(KeyForB());
}

void b(KeyForB /*unused*/){
}
```