# Golang Inheritance and method override

Tags: inheritance, go, overriding

Clarification: I'm just learning GO, and came across this problem.

I'm trying to implement a "class" that inherit a method that invokes a "virtual" method that should be implemented by the child class. Here's my code:

https://play.golang.org/p/ysiaPwARkvl

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type Parent struct {
  sync.Mutex
  MyInterface
}

func (p *Parent) Foo() {
  p.Lock()
  defer p.Unlock()
  p.Bar()
}

func (p *Parent) B(){
  panic("NOT IMPLEMENTED")
}

func (p *Parent) A() {
  p.Lock()
  defer p.Unlock()
  p.B()
}

type MyInterface interface {
  Foo()
  Bar()
}

type Child struct {
  Parent
  Name string
}

func (c *Child) Bar(){
  fmt.Println(c.Name)
}

func (c *Child) B(){
  fmt.Println(c.Name)
}

func main() {
  c := new(Child)
  c.Name = "Child"
  // c.A() panic
  c.Foo() // pointer error
}
```

I left out some code regarding the sync.Mutex that does some async update to the values of Child.

So apparently in A() or Foo() the pointer p have type Parent. How should I change my code so that A/Foo refer to B/Bar defined in the Child class?

Comment: Don't do that. This does not work, no matter how hard you try. You'll just hurt yourself. Leave inheritance based OOP behind.

Comment: Think of `c.A()` being a short form of `c.Parent.A()`. `c.Parent.A()` only has access to fields and methods in `c.Parent` and does not know about `c` itself.

Comment: This is an example of the template method pattern which is used in OOP for code reuse. In Go we reuse through composition, not through inheritance.

Comment: `I'm trying to implement a "class"` -- this is your first mistake. Don't do that in Go. Go doesn't have classes. Don't fight the language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're wanting an **is-a** relationship (inheritance) when Go only provides **has-a** relationships (composition):

- Go has no inheritance, thus there is no **is-a** relationship between two types.  `Child` is not a kind of `Parent`, so a pointer to a `Parent` cannot retain a pointer to a `Child`; `Child` **has-a** `Parent` contained within it instead.

Because there is no **is-a** relationship between `Parent` and `Child`, `Parent.Foo` cannot receive an object of type `Child`, nor can it use any of the methods that `Child` implements.  Also, this means that no `Parent` can access any method defined on a `Child` such as `Bar()` or `B()` directly.

Typically, `Parent` will not need to call some method in `Child`.  If it does, you'd pass the `Parent` method an argument, such as an interface that `Child` satisfies for you to call the method through the interface or a closure that calls the `Child` method:

```
// Use of an interface that Child satisfies.
type Beta interface {
    B()
}
func (p *Parent) A(b Beta) {
    p.Lock()
    defer p.Unlock()
    b.B()
}

// Use of a closure.
func (p *Parent) Foo(bar func()) {
    p.Lock()
    defer p.Unlock()
    bar()
}
func callFoo(p *Parent, c *Child) {
    callBar := func() {
        c.Bar()
    }
    p.Foo(callBar)
}

func (c *Child) Bar() {
    // stub
}

func (c *Child) B() {
    // stub
}
```

You get the *`Child` can call `Parent` method* behavior for free, but it only appears similar to inheritance. `child.Foo()` actually performs `child.Parent.Foo()`, which means `Parent.Foo` still receives a `Parent` instance (hence the name), not a `Child` instance.

However, `Parent` cannot access any information about `Child` that `Child` does not explicitly share.  Interfaces and closures can act as mechanisms between two classes analogous to the `friend` keyword in C++, except they're more restrictive than the `friend` keyword.  After all, `Child` doesn't need to share everything with `Parent`, just the bits that it wants to share, somewhat similar to [this pattern in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3220009/539810).  Personally I would prefer interfaces for this as it allows your `Parent` "class" to work with multiple types that all satisfy a common interface, making it pretty much the same as calling the method from a normal function or an entirely unrelated type's method.