# make_shared doesn't play along with enable_shared_from_this?

Tags: c++, boost-asio, shared-ptr

Consider the following two code snippets,
The first one:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <memory>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

class tcp_connection : public std::enable_shared_from_this<tcp_connection>
{
public:
    typedef std::shared_ptr<tcp_connection> pointer;

    static pointer create(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
    {
        return pointer(new tcp_connection(io_service));
        //second example only differs by replacing the above line with the below one
        //return std::make_shared<tcp_connection>(io_service);
    }

private:
    tcp_connection(boost::asio::io_service& io_service) //private constructor
        : socket_(io_service)
    {
    }
    tcp::socket socket_;
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

The second one only differs from the first with one line, that is, the commented line.

With MSVC 2017 and boost::asio 1.68, the first version works as intended, while the second one doesn't compile, spitting out errors such as "incomplete type is not allowed tcp_async".

My question is:

1. Is this because std::make_shared doesn't play along with std:std::enable_shared_from_this?
2. Or, it is because  assumptions that asio holds about how std::make_shared or std::enable_shared_from_this are implemented, doesn't hold with MSVC 2017.
3. Or it's something else?

Comment: Please edit the samples to a [mcve]. You don't need `boost::asio` to demonstrate the problem, the class definitions are illegal.

Comment: `std::make_shared` works quite well with `std::enable_shared_from_this`, this by itself shouldn't be the issue.

Comment: `make_shared` wont work as your constructor is private, can't reproduce your incomplete type errors though, please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem in the code you show stems from the constructor of your type being private.

When you write `new tcp_connection(io_service)` the constructor is being referred to in the scope of `tcp_connection` itself, which has access.

However, `std::make_shared` (or whatever implementation detail it may employ) doesn't have access to the private constructor, so it can't initialize the object it's meant to have a shared pointer manage.

If the initialization is well-formed, `std::make_shared` works splendidly with `std::enable_shared_from_this`, but a private constructor makes it ill-formed.

A common workaround to this is to use the [Passkey idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220009/is-this-key-oriented-access-protection-pattern-a-known-idiom). Which boils down to a public c'tor, but one that accepts a parameter of a private type. It would like somewhat like this<sup>1</sup>:

```
class tcp_connection2: public std::enable_shared_from_this<tcp_connection2>
{
    struct key{ explicit key(){} };
public:
    typedef std::shared_ptr<tcp_connection2> pointer;

    static pointer create(int io_service)
    {
        return std::make_shared<tcp_connection2>(io_service, key{});
    }

    tcp_connection2(int io_service, key) //private constructor, due to key
    {
    }
};
```

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> - I modified your class definition a bit, to make it easier for others to copy, paste and test this. But the same principle can be applied to your code.</sup>

Comment: You could add a reference to the key-pass idiom to still restrict constructor access even though made public for the sake of using `std::make_shared`? Anyway, +1.

Comment: @lubgr - I was just looking for a reference to that. Now added, thanks :)