# Make a friend class have only special access to 1 function of another class?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is this key-oriented access-protection pattern a known idiom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220009/is-this-key-oriented-access-protection-pattern-a-known-idiom)

I have `class A` and `class B`. I want `class A` to access one of `class B`'s private functions; but only that, not everything else. Is that possible?

Some kind of example:

```
class A {
  //stuff
};

class B {
  int r; // A cant use this
  MagicFriendKeyword A void func(); // A can use this
public:
  ...
};
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Is this key-oriented access-protection pattern a known idiom?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220009/is-this-key-oriented-access-protection-pattern-a-known-idiom).  That question gives an example of how you can achieve what you are asking; actually [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217390/clean-c-granular-friend-equivalent-answer-attorney-client-idiom) might be a better duplicate.

Comment: Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324898/can-we-increase-the-re-usability-of-this-key-oriented-access-protection-pattern), which seeks to generalize it. I think we ended up with the name "passkey friend idiom". The idea is that only certain classes can create a "passkey" type, and the function only accepts certain passkeys, granting access or "friendship".

Comment: There are more  --  and depending on context better  --  solutions than covered by the referenced discussions. In particular, factoring out `func` as an interface. Don't close open-ended questions, please, unless the similar old discussion is just as open-ended and complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is one (or few) members functions in class A, that want to use class B's private member functions, then you can declare those one/few functions as friend. E.g.

```
class B {
    // ...
    friend void A::mutateB( B * );
    // ...
};
```

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friend_function

Comment: I just want A to be able to call 1 private function of B.

Comment: I want all of class A to access one function of class B since hundreds of functions in A will use it.

Comment: This isn't what's asked. This still gives that function access to _all_ members of B. He wants to grant access to a single member of B.

Comment: @JoshD not really, I want to grant all of A access to one function of B which is private

Comment: @Milo:  Does the idiom described in the questions to which I linked in a comment to the question adequately resolve your issue?  If not, perhaps you can explain why so that people can better answer your question.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand their example, which part exactly demonstrates it?

Comment: @Milo: "Hundreds of functions in A will use it" you say?  Having a single class with hundreds of functions is terrible, you might want to look at cleaning up that problem first.

Comment: @All: Apologies. I answered the question at its 1st revision, and interpreting only from the text without the pseudo-code, I mis-interpreted it.