# Automatically add type derived class (not instances) to a list when created by programmer. c++

Tags: c++, class, templates, types, derived

So I am writing a program that will soon be passed on to another programmer. What I want to do is make it so he can create a new derived class from parent class `Process` [the actual code for it, not just a new instance], and it will automatically be added to lists which are used in other parts of the program. That way when he creates a derived class, he does not have to then go through and add it to other parts of the program to integrate it. All he has to do is make the class, and it is use-able with the program as is.

For example, part of the program prompts the user what type of process they want to run. If the next programmer is to add a new derived class to process, I want that process to automatically appear in the list of what processes the user can run.

Some code...
Programmer makes new header file such as (pseudo coded some parts for sanity, does not compile):

```
class Golay : public Process
{
public:
    virtual void run(Data data);
    static string processName = "golay";
};
```

The program runs and prompts user what process to run

```
cout << "What process would you like to run?" << endl;
for(iterate through all derived process classes here)
    cout << derivedClass::processName << endl;
cin >> processChoice;
runProcess(processChoice, data);
```

runProcess(string processName, Data data) would look something like this:

```
Process* process = NULL;
for(iterate through all derived process classes or an indexed map would be nice)
    if(processName == derivedClass::processName)
        process = new derivedClass;
process->run(data);
```

That's the idea of it. I want the for loop part for all derived processes to already be created when you make a new derived class header file. `runProcess()` will call functions as needed from the derived class. Otherwise I will just make an indexed `map<string, Template>` that the programmer has to add his newly derived class to manually.

I am lost on how to accomplish this, anyone have an idea?

Comment: It is not entirely clear how you add a class to a list. Perhaps show some example.

Comment: That's actually my question ^^^ how do I automatically add a new class type to a list that can be accessed. So all you have to do is make the header file.
That way instead of adding the new class name to a sea of if else statements for choosing a process, it is already integrated upon creation of the new class.

Comment: Show what you want to avoid, and how you want the client code look like. A sea of if else statements certainly would look nasty if we had to navigate it, but it isn't that clear where it would come from. Perhaps you really should show some code.

Answer (score 2):

Make illegal to derive from Process.

Create a CRTP `Process_Child<D>` that is the only class allowed to derive from Process.  `Process_Child<D>` uses private and friend to ensure that only `D` can derive from *it*, and in constructor checks that `D` actually derives from it (`static_assert`).

At this point, we are reasonably hardened.

`Process_Child<D>` has a private static data member that is referenced in its constructor (forcing it to exist if anyone writes code that constructs a `D` anywhere).  This private static data member doesn't have any state, but on construction it registers `Process_Child<D>`.

Suppose they write a process called `Bob`.  Bob is a `Process_Child<Bob>`.  They compile, get an error that `Process_Child<Bob>::registration_token` does not exist.  They declare that, and boom, done.

This doesn't auto-register: instead, it generates compile-time errors if registration doesn't happen.

We could step back and cause the registration to happen at the first construction of a `Process_Child<D>`, but that might never happen without it first being registered!

---

An alternative to runtime registration would be to maintain a list of types `template<class...>struct types{};` in one central place, and check using similar mechanisms that the type `D` in `Process_Child<D>` is in that list.

Instead of creating `Process_Child<D>::registration_token` in a `.cpp` file, the end-user instead has to modify a common header file to add `D` to the list of types.

Again, it doesn't happen automatically.  But failure to do it results in a build error.

Comment: These seems like the best solution so far. I haven't checked your answer yet though, in hopes that someone has found a way to automatically do this.

Comment: You won't be able to `static_assert` that `D` derives from the CRTP, because it won't be completely declared at the point of instanciation. You can, however, declare the constructor private and make `D` a friend.

Comment: @Quen do it in the ctor of the CRTP, not the body.  Ctor body isn't checked until derived class calls it, and by that point derivation is visible.

Comment: @Yakk so simple I never thought of it... Well. Thank you then :)

Answer (score 0):

This looks hard.
C++ is not designed to enable reflection.

Idea one, ask the second programmer to add a macro call like this

```
REGISTER(name_of_class)
```

either in his main call (if he writes the main)
or in the implementation file (the macro would need to expand to something that declares a variable (static would be enough) as the result of calling the function to register the class using its name)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in a totally automatic manner.  Your successor will have to invest some minimal work work in addition to writing the derived class (i.e. registering it).

For an example of how to do the registry see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31797099/implement-factory-pattern-for-products-with-conditional-compiling/31798047#31798047).  That answer also lists some of the caveats of this approach.