# Constexpr and know how count class

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, constexpr

I'm working on an Entity Component System and trying to make the Component type number based on how many class are derived from the Component class itself.

But I think there is some missing features in C++ for doing all I want.
Because the number of Component class should be some constexpr integer that I should use to delimit vector, bitmask etc...
For now I can just have every derived class have an unique type number, but can't detect the size of the bitset which is the number of derived class.

***Base:***

```
  //!
  //! \class ComponentBase
  //! \brief Exist only to manage CounterType in a prepocessor way
  //!
  class  ComponentBase {


    protected:
      static uint32_t  CounterType; // Counter of actual component number

    public:
      virtual ~ComponentBase() {}
  };
}

typedef std::bitset<ComponentBase::CounterType>  T_Mask;
```

***Derived:***

```
  //!
  //! \class Component
  //! \brief Superclass for Component, stock Type number and Manager
  //!
  template < typename Derived >
  class  Component : public ComponentBase {

    public:
      static const uint32_t             Type;

    protected:
      Component() = default;
  };
}

  template < typename Derived >
    const uint32_t  Component<Derived>::Type = ++ComponentBase::CounterType;
```

But right now I can't use CounterType to set the bitset size.
Tried with a constexpr but without any success.

If you have some ideas, I'm all ears.
Thanks anyways

Ps: I don't have any C++ limitation (G++ 6-2 right now)

Comment: Seriously, there is such a thing as too many comments. Especially for language features...

Comment: sorry, removed the code but forget comments! thanks

Comment: To answer your question, I don't think you can. The number of derived classes is unbound, and not always available when all translation units are compiled.

Comment: sounds like a nice case of the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: yeah but I wonder if C++ is able to resolve this problem, maybe with some constexpr tricks

Comment: Related as it might solve your _actual_ problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975672/c-automatic-factory-registration-of-derived-types

Comment: Not really my problem, but that could be useful in a near future so thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for is not possible in c++.

Assume your Base and Derived are available (transitively #included in) via `header.hpp` and are legal c++

You have the following files in your project:

1.cpp

```
#include "header.hpp"
class One {};

class ComponentOne : public Component<One> {};
```

2.cpp

```
#include "header.hpp"
class Two {};

class ComponentOne : public Component<Two> {};
```

You spin up cc.exe once to compile 1.cpp into 1.o, and another instance to compile 2.cpp into 2.o, what happens?

Comment: Arf you right, C++ doesn't look the whole code at once so that just impossible. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but yo will have to decide:

1. `std::bitset<size_t N>` requires a const(expr) number (something) for `N` so you can fix this, by having

   ```
   static const uint32_t CounterType = 1; // Counter of actual component number
   ```
2. But in this case: `++ComponentBase::CounterType;` will not work since you try to increment a constant variable.

I have the feeling there is something fishy with your design, so please share more behind the scene informations with us, in order to identify the problem more clearly.

Comment: Edited for more context.