# Ensure the user creates instance of a new subclass

Tags: c++, googletest, compile-time, static-assert

Let's say there is a base class

```
class Base
{
}
```

and the user has created a new subclass

```
class NewDerivedClass : public Base
{
}
```

There is also a enum for all the subclasses:

```
enum SubclassId
{
    Derived1_Id,
    Derived2_Id,
    ...
    NewDerivedClass_Id  // User has to add this line
}
```

Now, there is also a factory which creates derived instances based on the `SubclassId`:

```
class SubclassFactory
{
    Base* CreateSubclassInstance(SubclassId subclassId)
    {
        switch(subclassId)
        {
            case SubclassId::Derived1_Id:
                return new Derived1(params);
            case SubclassId::Derived2_Id:
                return new Derived2(params);
             ...

            // User has to add the following lines:
            case SubclassId::NewDerivedClass_Id:
                return new NewDerivedClass(params);
        }
    }
}
```

1. How can I force the user of my `Base` class to add new `Id` in enum?
2. How can I force the user of my `Base` class to create it's instance in `SubclassFactory`?

In the best case I would like to see a compile-time error. Unit test solution to this problem is also acceptable.

---

Additional information.
1. Users of the `Base` class create new subclasses in the client side.
2. My code operates in the backend. I get the subclass id remotely and use `Factory` to make instances of the subclasses created by client programmers.

Comment: What do you mean by a _unit test solution_?

Comment: Ok, why would You like to achieve this?

Comment: @Ron, by unit-test solution I mean a googletest which reports error in case the user has created it's own subclass, but he has forgotten to extend the body of `SubclassFactory`.

Comment: By requiring that users of your base class modify an existing enum every time they add a derived type, you are limiting the extensibility that polymorphism provides. Presumably, if you need a distinct type ID for every derived type, it's because you will eventually care about the concrete type of your objects. In most cases, proper use of polymorphism implies that you should not care about the concrete types. Consider where you will be using those IDs and how you will handle the addition of new types. It's likely polymorphism isn't the right solution to your problem.

Comment: @bartop, I want the members of the other team to see that they have made a mistake as soon as possible.

Comment: @Pixar Please [update](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48829298/edit) your post with the relevant information.

Comment: Just use template parameter for creating subclass, if they have made mistake, they will definitely see that :)

Comment: @Elvis, I am getting the id of the subclass from the network in run-time. I cannot use templates for that (probably). And I use Factory to create my own instance.

Comment: @François Andrieux, maybe you're right, but I cannot change the mechanism which was established way before me.

Comment: Nothing to force that in C++.  Comments in the code in the header around Base, team meetings to share the knowledge.  If a wayward developer does not abide by that, then get HR involved.

Comment: @Pixar If each derived type is required to return it's own ID, such as having a pure virtual function for that purpose, then defining that new ID becomes part of deriving your base type. An implementer would necessarily need to provide an override for that function and necessarily return some value from that override. If the documentation or comments are at all clear, the implementer would have no choice but to add a new id to the enum. Though this doesn't address the problem of adding a new entry to the factory function.

Comment: might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975672/c-automatic-factory-registration-of-derived-types