# C++ library avoid including sub classes

Tags: c++, oop, header-files

Let's say we have a library that has a class "Car" which has some private members of class "Wheel".

We want the user to be able to create a "Car" and use the "Drive" function(ality) of it.
This will also turn the wheels.

However, we want to avoid the user to create a "Wheel" by itself and turn it w/o the use of a car. To avoid them using the library improperly.

See example code below, where the main.cpp is the user code and the rest is the library.

---

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "car.h"

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
    Car myCar = Car();
    myCar.drive();
    
    //This should not be possible!
    Wheel someWheel = Wheel();
    someWheel.rotate();
    return 0;
}
```

car.h

```
class Wheel;//Forward declaration (to avoid '#include "wheel.h"', which would make it accessible in main.cpp.
class Car {
public:
    Car();
    void drive();
private:
    Wheel leftWheel;//Error, requires a pointer
};
```

car.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "car.h"
#include "wheel.h"

Car::Car(){
    leftWheel = new Wheel();
};
void Car::drive(){
    std::cout << "Vroom!"  << std::endl;
    leftWheel.rotate();
}
```

wheel.h

```
class Wheel {
public:
    Wheel();
    void rotate();
};
```

wheel.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "wheel.h"

Wheel::Wheel(){
};
void Wheel::rotate(){
    std::cout << "Wheel: *Rotates*"  << std::endl;    
}
```

---

We've found that by including the header file in the Car.cpp, we can achieve this.
However, when we make a forward declaration of 'Wheel', we can only use a pointer to Wheel as a private member from Car.

Otherwise it leads to:

> car.h:12:11: error: field ‘leftWheel’ has incomplete type ‘Wheel’

So my questions are:

- Should we at all hide 'Wheel' from the user, for his own 'safety'? Or is there a stronger reason not to do it?

  - If so, can we achieve this without the use of a pointer

    - If not, do we have to explicitly make a deconstructor that deletes the instance from memory?

Comment: Things that come to mind are : Let car depend on abstract base class (interface) of wheel  only (in its declaration), you can include in the car's definition (source file). Make the members of Car, std::unique_ptr<WheelItf> leftwheel; etc.. Or you can change the Car class to use the [pimpl pattern](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl), which will also hide ALL its implementation from other classes at compile (and runtime) time. It is also a good pattern to improve build speeds (parallel building)

Comment: Some libraries put the components in a nested namespace, like `detail` or `Private`, and then tell the users not to access that part. Is that not enough protection?

Comment: Why would you care if the users build their own cars or motorcycles or tractors or airplanes using the wheels provided by the library? What's wrong with that?

Comment: Hi, If ```Wheel``` are not for the user, technically you can achieve it as you did with a pointer (pimpl idiom as mentioned by PepijnKramer). You can also declare all its methods private and let ```Car``` be a friend (it should be better to use some trait (in order to let different classes use ```Wheel```) and [this attorney pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217390/clean-c-granular-friend-equivalent-answer-attorney-client-idiom)).
Besides encapsulating ```Wheel``` in some dedicated n,amespace, properly documented as *not for client* can do no harm (see Bop comment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the access you want the user to give to the `Wheel` class, simply restricting some members of the class to non-public visibility and making `Car` a friend can do the trick.

Alternatively you could make `Wheel` a `protected` nested class of a supertype.

Both of these alternatives result in a compiler complaining about the inaccessibility of members/types when trying to create a `Wheel` without a `Car`. This is closer to the message you're trying to convey ("Keep your hands of my `Wheel` class.") than a message about the type of `Wheel` being incomplete. (The latter is likely to be interpreted as "You're missing the correct #include".) Furthermore it avoids an extra dynamic allocation.

```
namespace UseFriends
{
class Car;

class Wheel
{
    friend class Car;

    Wheel() = default;
        
    Wheel(Wheel&&) = default;
    Wheel& operator=(Wheel&&) = default;

    Wheel(Wheel const&) = default;
    Wheel& operator=(Wheel const&) = default;
public:
    void rotate()
    {
        std::cout << "Wheel: *Rotates*" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Car
{
public:
    Car()
    {
    }

    void drive()
    {
        std::cout << "Vroom!" << std::endl;
        leftWheel.rotate();
    }
private:
    Wheel leftWheel;
};

} // namespace UseFriends

namespace UseNestedClass
{
class Vehicle
{
protected:
    class Wheel
    {
    public:
        void rotate()
        {
            std::cout << "Wheel: *Rotates*" << std::endl;
        }
    };
};

class Car : private Vehicle
{
public:
    Car()
    {
    }

    void drive()
    {
        std::cout << "Vroom!" << std::endl;
        leftWheel.rotate();
    }
private:
    Vehicle::Wheel leftWheel;
};

} // namespace UseNestedClass

int main()
{
    {
        using Car = UseFriends::Car;
        using Wheel = UseFriends::Wheel;

        std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
        Car myCar = Car();
        myCar.drive();

        Wheel someWheel = Wheel(); // compiler error: UseFriends::Wheel::Wheel() is inaccessible
        someWheel.rotate();
    }

    {
        using Car = UseNestedClass::Car;
        using Wheel = UseNestedClass::Vehicle::Wheel; // compiler error: UseNestedClass::Vehicle::Wheel is inaccessible

        std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
        Car myCar = Car();
        myCar.drive();
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, we did learn about 'Friend class', but didn't expect it to be applicable for this situation.
Though it feels more 'safe' as using pointers.