# Making a class method private/protected but making it accessible if its composed within another class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, composition

In C++, there are `public, private, protected` attributes/methods which provide different sets of permissions for inheritance.

I have a design issue where I have a class `A`, and a class `B` has an attribute of type `A`. So I'm using composition here. There's a method `func` in `A` that I want `B` to be able to access, but I don't want it to be accessible if, say, an instance of `A` was created outside of `B`, i.e., `func` is only accessible if `A` is composed within `B`. Is there a way to achieve this in C++?

Example:

```
class A {
private:
  // I made it private here, but I want func to be accessible within `B`
  void func() {
    // implementation omitted
  }
};

class B {
public:
  B() : a(A{}) {}
  void some_method_that_calls_func() {
    // I want to be able to access a.func()
  }
private:
  A a;
}
```

So in this example, the only way I know how to access `a.func()` is to make `func` public, but I don't want to expose this `func` method to be entirely public, and I only want it to be called within `B`.

Comment: why does an `A` that is created outide of `B` have the method `func` at all? Perhaps "an instance of A was created outside of B" and "if A is composed within B" are actually two different types? one with `func`, the other without.

Comment: what is `A` and `B` actaully? I am afraid you abstracted away all details that would be necessary to come up with a sound design

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai they're classes. Let me provide a simple example

Comment: why can't `func` be in `B` and use the getters from `A` to do it's calculations?

Comment: You could make `A` a `friend` of `B`, but this could be a sign of bad design. Why does `B` need special privileges? What if a different class wants to use `A` in the same manner?

Comment: sure they are classes, but what are those classes? Why does `A` have a method that not all instances need? Why is it possible to create an `A` outside of `B` when there is nothing you can do with it?

Comment: look for key/keyring pattern (or [client/attorney](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217390/clean-c-granular-friend-equivalent-answer-attorney-client-idiom), just the same)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai I think there's an existing design problem with this set of classes. `A` is used in other cases in standalone mode where most of the methods are relevant, but `func` is not. When `A` is used within `B` however, all of the methods (including `func`) are used

Comment: Sounds like maybe a `friend` is what you are looking for..?

Comment: @JesperJuhl I think that can work here. But these comments are now making me think I might want to redesign this set of classes

Comment: You could make an interface (abstract baseclass) derive publically from it but keep implementation private. Then other classes can get to the "internal" methods by casting the object to the "private" interface. Not completely fool proof but at least you can quickly scan code for misuse (the cast to that interface). And you could also put the header file for that interface in a special location

Comment: If `A` works differently in different places, perhaps it should be two different classes? Poissibly inheriting from a common base.

Comment: @BoP yes, that's what i was thinking of doing. similar to what Pepijin above you suggested as well

with that said, I haven't coded in C++ in awhile and forgot that `friend` existed (that answers the underlying question)

Answer (score 0):

By using the friend keyword in class A, you specify that B has access to its private members. This allows you to maintain the encapsulation you want, where func is only accessible within B, without exposing it as public to the rest of your codebase. Other classes won't have access to func.

```
class A {
private:
    void func() {
        
    }

    friend class B;
};

class B {
public:
    B() : a(A{}) {}

    void some_method_that_calls_func() {
        a.func(); // Access func because B is a friend of A
    }
private:
    A a;
};
```