# CRTP: restrict access of Base class to some members of Derived class

Tags: c++, friend, crtp

Consider a CRTP pattern `template <class DerivedType> class Base`. I would like to:

1. Base class cannot be instantiated
2. (Some) methods in Derived class can called only through the "interface" of the Base class
3. Base class can access to only some of the private members of Derived

To satisfy 1., it is enough to declare the constructor of the Base class `protected`. To satisfy 2., it is possible to make the methods private, and declare the Base class `friend`. This will however allow Base to access *all* members of Derived.

See for example this code:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class Base {
protected:
  Base() = default;

public:
  void interface() const { static_cast<const T*>(this)->do_something(); }

  // This should not compile
  void interface_to_private() const { static_cast<const T*>(this)->do_something_private(); }
};

class Derived : public Base<Derived> {
  friend class Base<Derived>;
  void do_something() const { do_something_private(); }
  // These should be not available to Base<Derived>
  int i = 1;
  void do_something_private() const { std::cout << "hello " << i << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
  Derived d;
  d.interface();
  d.interface_to_private(); // This should give error

  return 0;
}
```

In the example code I would like `Base<Derived>` to have access to `do_something()`, but not to `do_something_private()`, nor to the member field `int i`.

I am aware that granularity of `friend` access is a known problem, that can, for example, be solved by the [Attorney-Client idiom](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Friendship_and_the_Attorney-Client). However, I was not able to figure out if it can be really combined to the CRTP idiom. It goes without saying, that I do not want virtual members (this is the whole point of using CRTP).

I found a solution by hiding the methods in another class:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class Base {
protected:
  Base() = default;

public:
  void interface() const { static_cast<const T*>(this)->do_something(); }
  // This should not compile
  void interface_to_private() const { static_cast<const T*>(this)->do_something_private(); }

};

class Implementation {
  int i = 1;
  void do_something_private() const { std::cout << "hello " << i << std::endl; }

protected:
  Implementation() = default;
  
public:
  void do_something() const { do_something_private(); }
};

class Derived : public Base<Derived>, private Implementation {
  friend class Base<Derived>;
};

int main()
{
  Derived d;
  d.interface();
  // uncommenting gives compile error
  // d.interface_to_private();

  return 0;
}
```

Uncommenting the line `d.interface_to_private();` cause a compilation error.

While this appears to work, it seems involved, and I wonder if it is a good solution given that multiple inheritance is generally [frowned upon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406081/why-should-i-avoid-multiple-inheritance).

Is there a better solution, or a known "idiom" for this case?

Comment: [client/attorney pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217390/clean-c-granular-friend-equivalent-answer-attorney-client-idiom). AKA key/keyring

Comment: CRTP was never meant to access derived members from the base class... If you have to do that, then your designed is flawed. CRTP is about injecting implementation.

Comment: for the base class construction, declare protected constructor (for letting derived class construct the base part) and a virtual destructor.

Comment: @Fareanor: In CRTP, the base can make call to child member functions? Isn't it the purpose of instantiating the base with the child as template argument?

Comment: @Oersted According to me, it's an unfortunate open door. The true purpose of CRTP is to inject implementation (contrary to virtual inheritance which is about injecting interface). I made a [simple example to illustrate this here](https://godbolt.org/z/ejWvozax6). In this small example, each derived class will get a correctly prototyped `clone()` function.

Comment: simplest way to do 2. is same method that allows to access private without `friend`. I.e. you have a nested class type, inherited from `Derived`

Comment: @Oersted I forgot to add a copy constructor to make my example work, [Here it is](https://godbolt.org/z/ePPWaY7bq)

Comment: Make **attorney** a member; no need to befreind member classes. I've always done this - without giving it a name.

Comment: Maybe this is useful, but it strikes me as a strange thing to be concerned about. The `Base` template defines its requirements to be used. It cannot randomly try to access arbitrary members of a derived class without the risk of breaking some other derived class. (And `Derived` could always drop `Base` if `Base` misbehaves.) This is rather different than arbitrary code accessing members of the derived class. Arbitrary code *uses* `Derived`, and `Derived` *uses* `Base`. Protection levels seem to me more of a guard against code that uses yours, rather than code you use.

Comment: @Fareanor CRTP is actually C++ implementation of TWO distinct patterns - a mixin, which you described, and of functional polymorphism within class (it's a static type of polymorphism). In C++23 the latter can be implemented by deduce this feature without chicken-and-egg problem of incomplete types.

Comment: *"that can, for example, be solved by the Attorney-Client idiom."* [passkey idiom](https://arne-mertz.de/2016/10/passkey-idiom/) is another option.

Comment: _Base class can access to only some of the private members of Derived_ Can't you just make those members `protected`?

Comment: @Fareanor I generally use CRTP when I partially specialized template class. I put the common implementation inside a base class and make it CRTP if it requires to call, from a base member function, some method whose implementation varies with the specialization. I always thought that CRTP was a good design for this goal.